# Egit, Eclipse folder structure

Tags: egit

Let's say I have several projects in c:\dev\ and want to keep them there (this is my eclipse workspace)

What is the least inconvenient way to setup egit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349404) in egit where you cannot create a git repo on an existing folder

You need to use msysgit to create the git repo on the command line, using git init

Then you can use egit as per the user guide